# Calling function inside other function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Have an Person function defined as below,

```
function Person() {
    this.GetContactDetail = function() {

        // Can I make a call to GetFullDetail  function over here is it possible , 
        // I tried but it doesnt calls the GetFullDetail  function
        this.GetFullDetail; 
    };

    this.GetFullDetail = function() {

    };
};

var objPer = new Person();
objPer.GetContactDetail();
```

The above code is just an snippet for the reference.

Comment: `this.GetFullDetail();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call a function in javascript, you should use () after its name. Just referencing it, will not call it.

So above you should do something like this:

```
this.GetFullDetail();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function like

```
  this.GetFullDetail();
```

This `this.GetFullDetail;` shows the `Person variable`.

Answer (score -1):

`this` inside GetContactDetails doesn't refers to `Person` but to the `GetContactDetails` context. You should save a reference to `this` outside.

```
function Person() {
     var _self = this;
     this.GetContactDetail = function () { 
        _self.GetFullDetail(); 
        ...
```

Comment: Thats not correct. It were, if the function were `function GetContactDetail ()`.